# Increase Azure SQL Server PITR to 35 days with ARM template

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template, azure-sql-server

I have a ARM template like below which creates a SQL server.

```
{
        "name": "Name",
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
        "location": "EastUS2",            
        "properties": {
            "administratorLogin": "****",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "******"
        },
        "resources": [
            ...         
        ]
    }
```

Its PITR time is set to 7 days and I would like to increase it to 35 days. But I could not find a way through ARM template. Can the PITR time be increased from ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL database ARM template doesn't has the option to set the  PITR time. In one word, we can't set it with ARM template.

Ref here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.sql/sql-database-transparent-encryption-create/azuredeploy.json.

Comment: Is this confirmed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be increased from ARM template. Child resource of [`Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/2021-11-01/servers/databases/backupshorttermretentionpolicies) type needs to be created like this:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies",
  "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
  "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('sqlServerName'), variables('databaseName'), 'default')]",
  "properties": {
    "retentionDays": 14
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', variables('sqlServerName'), variables('databaseName'))]"
  ]
},
```